# databaseAuthVariableOverride not limiting permission to cloud admin sdk

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am using `databaseAuthVariableOverride` in cloud functions to Initialize firebase with a custom auth variable to limit its permissions, however it is still acting with full write and read permission.

This is how I am Initializing, admin is suppose to have full permission but I want restrictedadmin to have limited permission based on database rules. but they both have full permission.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var restrictedadmin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = 
require(functions.config().theserviceaccountcey.path);

restrictedadmin.initializeApp({

  credential: restrictedadmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),

  databaseURL: "thedatabaseurl",
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: "Y2czfP3Zr1b6GBltyqx0GNHccVw1"
  }
}, 'restricedadmin');
```

please assist, thank you